# Change the public static variable by a non static method

Tags: java, static-variables

I am implementing the same in a different context. I want to change the value of a static variable by calling non static Method as below,

```
public static staticVar = changetheStatic();
public String changetheStatic(){
return "valueChanged";`
}
```

I am getting error like the "Change the method to static".. so any suggestions..??

Comment: put a `static` after the access modifier

Comment: `public static staticVar = changetheStatic();` ==> Your code won't compile

Answer (score 2):

This simply can't work.

You can only invoke **non** static methods on some **instance**. In your example, there is no instance; thus the compiler would only allow you to call a **static** method.

And just for the record: the naming is confusing. You called your method *changeTheStatic()*. But that method doesn't change *anything*. It only returns a value. So you should be calling it something like *getInitialValue()* for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. You are trying to call an instance method without initializing an object. Instead what you can do is do this in you constructor

```
          public class A {
           public static staticVar ;

           public A() {
                  A.staticVar = this.changetheStatic()
           }
           public String changetheStatic(){
             return "valueChanged";`
           }
         }
```

If you don't want to change it in the constructor, you can simply initialize an object and call the instance method

```
                System.out.println(A.staticVar);//old value
                new A().changetheStatic();//will call instant method related to the new instantiated object , note i did not give it a reference so GC will free it cuz i only need it to change the static variable

                System.out.println(A.staticVar);//new value
```

The whole idea here is what you are doing is trying to call instant method as static, instant method needs to be called from an object

```
         public static staticVar = changetheStatic();
```

so changing `changetheStatic()` to static would work too.

Comment: yes, But If I want to access the static variable from another class with out declaring as local.

Comment: You can access it from anywhere as long its public , the idea is if you want to access it from instant method you need to instantiate an object and call that method from there, otherwise you will need to change it from a static method

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply call methods like this as static variables are created when the class is initialised. It means that these static variables will exist even if there's no instance of the class.

Hence you can only do this by changing the `changetheStatic()` method to static

```
public static staticVar = changetheStatic();
public static String changetheStatic(){
    return "valueChanged";`
}
```